# python2.7-dev unmet dependencies on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, apt-get

I installed python2.7 on Ubuntu Lucid a couple of months ago through a PPA. Everything went fine and there was no problem. Yesterday, I upgraded from lucid to Ubuntu Precise and the upgrade went smoothly. Now, I need to install python2.7-dev and I get unment dependencies error:

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7-dev
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python2.7-dev : Depends: python2.7 (= 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.2) but 2.7.4-1+lucid1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libpython2.7 (= 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.2) but 2.7.4-1+lucid1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This is clearly caused by my old python2.7 that I installed on lucid. To fix that, I wanted to remove python2.7 and reinstall it (`apt-get remove python2.7`), but I realized it will remove a lot of packages and will install python3 instead. So I did not do that. How can I get rid of my old python2.7 and install a new one that works with Precise?

Note that my PPAs are all disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command fixed the problem.

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7-minimal=2.7.3-0ubuntu3.2 python2.7=2.7.3-0ubuntu3.2 libpython2.7=2.7.3-0ubuntu3.2
```